# How can I lookup data in a sheet, amend it and then write back amended data into that row with a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a workbook where I can view existing records, add new records and amend existing records stored in a table. I have View, Input and Amend sheets along with the Data sheet. I already have a way of adding new records (copied from another workbook and edited to suit):

```vb
Sub add_to_table()
    Dim NewRow As Integer
    NewRow = Worksheets("input").Range("H1").Value + 1
    If Worksheets("input").Range("I1").Value <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are errors. No data has been added!", vbOKOnly, "Warning!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 1).Value = 
    Worksheets("input").Range("B3").Value
    Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 2).Value = 
    Worksheets("input").Range("B4").Value

   '(there are 66 columns)

    Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 66).Value = 
    Worksheets("input").Range("F22").Value
    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("B2").Value = "Data added"
    MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly, "Transfer Data"
           
    Worksheets("input").Range("H1").Value = NewRow
    Worksheets("input").Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

In the View sheet I use a combi box to list the entries and display a row number, for which I use INDEX to show a value which I can use for LOOKUPs to display the rest of the row. In the Input sheet I have a blank set of headed cells for entering new entries and use a macro using the above code to add a new row. I was hoping to  use a combi box in the Amend sheet to select an entry and then use the row number to tell the macro which row to amend using the above code modified for the Amend sheet and less the +1. The macro would also put the lookups back for reuse where they have been over written. Unfortunately it doesn't work and Googling doesn't seem to find any relevant answers. So could someone assist me please. Thank you.

Comment: "it doesn't work" - you mean the not-posted code isn't working?  You'd need to post it if you want help fixing it...

Answer (score 0):

One way or another by closely checking and trying different things the macro now works up to a point.

```
Sub amend_table()

  'Written by Keith Cooper 10/10/2021

  Dim NewRow As Integer
  NewRow = Worksheets("amend").Range("G1").Value


  Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 1).Value = Worksheets("amend").Range("B3").Value
  Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 2).Value = Worksheets("amend").Range("B4").Value
  Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 3).Value = Worksheets("amend").Range("D3").Value

  '66 columns

  Worksheets("Data").Cells(NewRow, 66).Value = 
  Worksheets("amend").Range("F22").Value
  Sheets("Amend").Select
           Range("H7").Value = "Data amended"
           MsgBox "Data added", vbOKOnly, "Amend Data"
           

  'Worksheets("input").Range("H1").Value = NewRow
  Worksheets("amend").Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

The up to a point is that the next part of the macro isn't doing what it should, it isn't adding VLOOKUPs back into the cells correctly, but that should probably be another post.